# Why I can't get value from Jquery to php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to make a dynamic combobox in php and jquery, but can't use the data of the post

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var cambio = $('#categoria');
categoria1 = $(cambio).val();   
console.log(categoria1);
$.post('agregar_productos.php',{categoria1:categoria1},function(){

});
})
```

My php code

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['categoria1']) && strlen(trim($_POST['categoria1']))): ?>
                    <?php  
                    header('location: '.$_POST['categoria1'].'.php');/*This work in console GET http://localhost:8080/jecommerce/views/Computacion.php 404 (Not Found)*/
/* echo $_POST['categoria1]; but this doesn't work, can't show code and can't use html */?>
                <?php endif ?>
```

Also, i tried

```
$.ajax({
        url:'agregar_productos.php',
        method:"POST",
        data:{categoria1:categoria1},  
        success:function(){

        }
})
```

why echo doesn't work?

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(categoria1)`?

Comment: You cannot do a `header('location:` from `AJAX` --  You will need a different approach .. After your AJAX is run, you will need a callback in the JS and do a `window.location.replace`

Comment: The output of console.log(categoria1) is Computacion

Comment: @Zak while I agree with you, I feel like the point of Ajax is specifically to make it so you don't have to redirect.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton  --  I wasn't saying that he *should* redirect -- Just if he was going to -- He's going about it wrong.  And you are right ...  The purpose of `AJAX` is do give a clean "seamless" feel

Comment: Of course, but i did it only for get the response and see the value

Comment: @Zak Yeah I guess my message was more for OP than you, even though I tagged you. I didn't really assume you were condoning redirecting with Ajax, I was just expanding on your point stating that it's not really "best practice"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short Ajax with Ajax post .missing parameter response on callback

header(page.php) maybe not return response Ajax ...
Try echo "hello"; on aggregar_productos.php

```
$.post('agregar_productos.php',{categoria1:categoria1},function(response){

console.log(response);

});
```

Php code

```
if($_POST['categoria1']) && strlen(trim($_POST['categoria1']))): ?>
                    <?php  
                      inlucde($_POST['categoria1'].'.php');
                <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did everything in the same file so I returned the whole file, and when I did it in another file I didn't return everything, I guess because of the stress, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this case, trying returning the data instead of echo, but 'echo' works perfectly fine.

Also, you missed an important callback variable in which you will get the response back from PHP to your AJAX script

```
$.post('agregar_productos.php', {categoria1:categoria1}, function(return_data){

   console.log(return_data);

});
```